# While reloading or repainting QTableWidget it adds blank rows and write data after these blank rows

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

The function is to read the hard drive partitions from a text file. The function is working fine, but when I want to reload the table after the change in partition layout, it add the blank row of the same quantity as displayed previously and starts writing data rows after words.

```
void PartitionPage::processPartitions(QString line, int numberOfRows){
static int row = 0;
QStringList partitions = line.split(":");
qDebug() << numberOfRows;

//qDebug() << partitions.count();

if(partitionTable->rowCount() < (row + 1))
    partitionTable->setRowCount(row + 1);

// we  want to dispay first 7 columns only
//if(partitionTable->columnCount() < partitions.size())
//    partitionTable->setColumnCount( partitions[0].size() );

// Set Header Label Texts Here
// set the columncount to 7 as we only want to display first 7 column
partitionTable->setColumnCount(7);
partitionTable->setColumnWidth(0, 120);
partitionTable->setColumnWidth(1, 120);
partitionTable->setColumnWidth(2, 120);
partitionTable->setColumnWidth(3, 120);
partitionTable->setColumnWidth(4, 120);
partitionTable->setColumnWidth(5, 120);
partitionTable->setColumnWidth(6, 120);

partitionTable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Partition; Start Sector; End Sector; Total Sectors; Partition Size; Partition ID; File System").split(";"));

for( int column = 0; column < partitionTable->columnCount(); column++){
    QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    newItem->setText(partitions.at(column));
    partitionTable->setItem(row, column, newItem);
    newItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
}
row++;
partitionTable->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
partitionTable->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

}

Blank rows

[image]

Comment: How do you reload or repaint the widget?

Comment: // after gparted find partition and reload table, as user may change the partitions
    partitionTable->clear();
    findPartitions();
    delay(3000);
    partitionTable->repaint(); 
    qApp->processEvents();

Comment: You could share your project if it is minimal, if it is not, you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: How can I share? It has only one .CPP, a header file and sone Linux scripts. I could not understand Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I am working on my own Linux distribution.

Comment: Have you read the content of the link ?, In addition to asking the above you could share it through github, drive, dropbox or similar.

Comment: I have add a picture. Kindly have a look and guide please.

Comment: why do you use a static variable: `static int row = 0 ;`? they try to change it to `int row = 0;`

Comment: Also do not use the sleep.

Comment: If I use the `int row = 0` instead of `static int row = 0`  then I gen only tone row data i.e. the last line of text file.

Comment: in the `for` verify the value of row, I think it has never been reset, therefore you are placing the Qtablewidgetitem in an inadequate position.

Comment: Sir, If I run for loop on rows as well as on column then also I get only one row data i.e. last line of the text file. `for ( int row = 0; row < numberOfRows + 1; row++){
       for( int column = 0; column < partitionTable->columnCount(); column++){
            QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
            newItem->setText(partitions.at(column));
            partitionTable->setItem(row, column, newItem);
            newItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        }
    }`

Comment: I can not help anymore, I feel with my hands tied because I could not provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Qt have many bugs in view-model system. Your most funny.

Possible solutions:

1) Try use another Qt version.

2) Try make table with QTableView and own "model" (children of QAbstractTableModel) That will not simple for first time. But can help

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try it.